# how to define user who run puppet script as variable

Tags: puppet

I am using puppet, what I am trying to write script that create file related to the user who run it. lets say I want to create the file/soft link if not exist so other application can edit it, then move it to archive.

```
file { '/some/path/myuser.file':
    ensure => 'link',     -- ensure => 'file', if I want to create file
    target => '/orignal/path/file',
     }
```

Note: myuser should be edited by the actual user who ran the script
If I make the script fixed like below it will work without any issue:

```
file { '/some/path/aabuhasna.file':
        ensure => 'link',  -- ensure => 'file', if I want to create file
        target => '/orignal/path/file',
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is core fact within puppet called `id`, which "return the user identifier (UID) of the user running facter.": https://docs.puppet.com/facter/latest/core_facts.html#id

So it should be possible to simply use:

```
file { "/some/path/${id}":
  ensure => 'link',
  target => '/original/path/file',
}
```

Comment: Thanks, while debugging the scripts, found the core facter is not loaded as expected, had to remove then and installed them from  http://downloads.puppetlabs.com/facter